# In Lean, contradiction tactic failed but actually goal accomplished

Tags: lean, proof-review, lean3

I've been playing with `Lean`, trying to prove the next lemma:

```
lemma l1_cl (A B C : Prop) : ((A →  B) → C) → ((A ∧ ¬ B) ∨ C) :=
```

Here is the proof I've currently written:

```
begin
  intro h,
  cases classical.em C; cases classical.em A; cases classical.em B; try {right, assumption};
  {right, apply h, intro hA, contradiction},
  {sorry},{sorry},{sorry}
end
```

First `{}` seems okay; here is the **Tactic state** right before the `contradiction`:

```
1 goal
ABC: Prop
h: (A → B) → C
h_1: ¬C
h_2: ¬A
h_3: ¬B
hA: A
⊢ B
```

So, I have that `h_2: ¬A` and `hA: A`, which should lead to the contradiction. Applying `contradiction` in `Coq` thus leads to completing the goal.

But here in `Lean` something strange occurs: in **Tactic state** window I get the notification `goals accomplished` , whileas in **Messages** I get `contradiction tactic failed` with the next state:

```
state:
A B C : Prop,
h : (A → B) → C,
h_1 : ¬C,
h_2 : A,
h_3 : ¬B,
hA : A
⊢ B
```

So it seems like `h_2` somehow has been changed, and this might lead to that message, although the goal is completed. Probably I've used `contradiction` tactic in the wrong way, but I don't see that for now. Can anyone help me to figure things out and to get rid of the message?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue is the `;` at the end of the long line. This is causing the `{right, ...}` block to be applied to *all* goals, meaning that the `{sorry}` blocks never have a chance to run, and the error you are getting at `contradiction` is in the second invocation on the block on the second goal. Change the `;` to `,` to fix the issue:

```
lemma l1_cl (A B C : Prop) : ((A →  B) → C) → ((A ∧ ¬ B) ∨ C) :=
begin
  intro h,
  cases classical.em C;
    cases classical.em A;
    cases classical.em B;
    try {right, assumption}, -- <- note the comma
  {sorry},
  {sorry},
  {right, apply h, intro hA, contradiction},
  {right, apply h, intro hA, contradiction},
end
```

(Actually, as you can see the provided proof only works on goals 3 and 4; it is the first two that fail.)

Alternatively, you can keep the `;` but use `try` to apply the block anywhere it works:

```
lemma l1_cl (A B C : Prop) : ((A →  B) → C) → ((A ∧ ¬ B) ∨ C) :=
begin
  intro h,
  cases classical.em C;
    cases classical.em A;
    cases classical.em B;
    try {right, assumption}; -- <- note the semicolon
    try {right, apply h, intro hA, contradiction},
  {sorry},{sorry},
end
```

---

Or if you are feeling lazy (and are using mathlib)

```
import tactic.tauto
lemma l1_cl (A B C : Prop) : ((A → B) → C) → ((A ∧ ¬ B) ∨ C) :=
by tauto!
```

Comment: Thank you! The 2nd scenario works fine! But via the 1st one, the message persists: it seems that the provided proof works on goals 1 and 2, at least this is what I get in the **Tactic state**. Nevertheless, applying the proof to first 2 cases, the problem is gone.

Comment: Because the three `cases` appear in the order `C`, `A`, `B` and `classical.em` has the type `p ∨ ¬p` which puts the positive case first, the first four goals have `h_1 : C` and are killed by the `try` block, and the latter four have `h_1: ¬C`, and `h_2, h_3` have types [`A,B`; `A,¬B`; `¬A,B`; `¬A,¬B`] in that order. Since the proof is assuming `A` and trying to get a contradiction, the latter two goals (3 and 4) are provable by this method, while goals 1 and 2 need a different approach. (In other words, the code should be correct as written unless `em` or the cases were done in another order.)